# How to correctly scale new data points sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, scaling

Imagine a simple regression problem, where you are using Gradient Descent. For correct implementation you will need to scale values using mean of entire training dataset. Imagine your model is already trained and you feed it another example you wish to predict. How do you scale it correctly with respect to previous dataset? Do you include new example in training set and then scale it with mean of this training dataset + new data points? How this should be done the right way?

By referring to new data points i mean something the model hasn't seen before, neither in training nor testing. How do you handle scaling for anything you pass to regr.predict() if scaling of training set is done with respect to the whole set and not a single observation.

Imagine you have ndarray of features:

```
to_predict = [10, 12, 1, 330, 1311, 225].
```

The dataset used for train and test is already oscillating around 0 for every feature. Taking into account the below answer (pseudo code, that's why I'm asking how to do it right):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()

new_Xs = X_train.append(to_predict)

X_train_std_with_new = scalar.fit_transform(new_Xs)

scaled_to_predit = X_train_std_with_new[-1]

regr.predict(scaled_to_predict) ??
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not able to scale the training/testing before training? To avoid the issue you mentioned, it's advised to scale the data before training